# jmeter 3.0 -e -o Command-Line Issues "folder not empty"

Tags: jmeter

Reference http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html, but always being given to the last command line when running -e -o "folder not empty" do not know how to solve?(jmeter3.0)
[image]

Comment: -e -o <Path to output folder>
I set Path = G: \, but still wrong, I do not know if this path is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested yesterday . by placing just "tmp" after -o . it created a folder called tmp in bin directory of jmeter .

Note .. when new reports are generating JMETER uses "temp" as a temporary folder and then it transfers to userfolder in my case it was tmp . I tried you way . I dont have any folder named "tmp" in C drive then i got the below message.

```
C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>jmeter.bat -g mylog.jtl -o C:\tmp\suman
Writing log file to: C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter.log
An error occurred: Cannot write to 'C:\tmp\suman' as folder does not exist and parent folder is not writable
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

and then I created a parent folder "tmp" in c drive and excuted the same command again this time i am through it

```
C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>jmeter.bat -g mylog.jtl -o C:\tmp\suman
    Writing log file to: C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter.log
    C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>
```

Next I tried your way i created a folder "madan" and i kept some files in it and then I tried pointing to that directory, I have got same message what are you seeing .

```
C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>jmeter.bat -g mylog.jtl -o C:\tmp\madan
Writing log file to: C:\JMETER\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter.log
An error occurred: Cannot write to 'C:\tmp\madan' as folder is not empty
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I also tried , is the reason for error in the file name , G: \ must give it back a file , for example : -e -o G: \ xxx This right , thank you for your advice :)

Comment: I am glad that , it was useful for you

Answer (score 4):

Like you can see in the Jmeter documentation :

***-o
output folder where to generate the report dashboard after load test. Folder must not exist or be empty***

I think it is so amazing from Jmeter !!!

Best Regards

Ludo

Comment: Yes, but I found a new problem Reference "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387610/generating-report-dashboard-errors-number"the resulting report errors number is not correct, the value is always more than the actual situation 1 (cvs, only five false, but the display 6 errors number)

Answer (score 3):

Use -f flag in your command.
-f will force delete existing results files before start the test