# Generating Report Dashboard Errors number

Tags: jmeter, apdex

I refer http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configure_general, the resulting report errors number is not correct , the value is always more than the actual situation 1 (cvs , only five false, but the display 6 errors number), I do not know bug or I did not find the configuration of the place is not Jmeter3.0 ?

[image]

Comment: Today they tried it or not , errors number value and cvs in inconsistent, always one more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reported minor issue in JMeter :

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59621

Error count in report dashboard is one off.

It is now fixed in jmeter nightly build:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

Comment: Honor can be found bug was jmeter, the "59621"problem is my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to generate HTML report as you showed in your screenshot, evn though I have configured as per instructions. And also in the csv file I am anot able to see the Label.

```
Could you please guide me,where am i missing.

**My jmeterproperties file settings:**


# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv


# true when field should be saved; false otherwise

# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#
# legitimate values: none, first, all
#jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=none
#
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=true

# Timestamp format - this only affects CSV output files
# legitimate values: none, ms, or a format suitable for SimpleDateFormat
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=ms
jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

My UserProperties file settings:
 Configure this property to change the report title
jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=TimeTrax Performance Test JMeter Report Dashboard

# Change this parameter if you want to change the granularity of over time graphs.
jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=60000

# Change this parameter if you want to change the granularity of Response time distribution
# Set to 500 ms by default
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.responseTimeDistribution.property.set_granularity=500

# Change this parameter if you want to keep only some samples.
# Regular Expression which Indicates which samples to keep for graphs and statistics generation.
# Empty value means no filtering
#jmeter.reportgenerator.sample_filter=

# Change this parameter if you want to override the APDEX satisfaction threshold.
#jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=500
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=1500

# Change this parameter if you want to override the APDEX tolerance threshold.
#jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=1500
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=3000

# Indicates which graph series are filtered (regular expression)
# In the below example we filter on Search and Order samples
# Note that the end of the pattern should always include (-success|-failure)? 
# TransactionsPerSecondGraphConsumer suffixes transactions with "-success" or "-failure" depending 
# on the result
#jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=(Search|Order)(-success|-failure)?

# Indicates whether only controller samples are displayed on graphs that support it.
#jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.show_controllers_only=false

# Indicates whether series filter apply only on sample series or to all series
# setting this to false can lead to empty graphs if series_filter does not
# contain required series
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.filters_only_sample_series=true

Thanks,
Raj
```

Comment: hi @rpagadala  I was completely in accordance with the official documents to configure , so I believe that if you follow documentation to complete the configuration can also be "http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#configure_general"

Answer (score -1):

I have given good explanation report dashboard generation in this StachExchange Question,please follow same steps to generate HTML reports for your test plan.

[How do I generate a Dashboard Report in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263768/how-do-i-generate-a-dashboard-report-in-jmeter/39998477#39998477)