# How do I generate a Dashboard Report in jmeter?

Tags: java, graph, jmeter, report

I am running jmeter2.12 on Fedora.

What are the steps to generate a Dashboard Report?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

steps:

- 1.Add 'Summary Report', 'Simple Data Writer' from Listeners.
- 2.Set location to generated csv
- 3.open reportgenerator.properties from "D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\" copy all content from it
- 4.Open user.properties from same bin folder
- 5.Append all from reportgenerator.properties to user.properties and save
- 6.Now run the your Test script
- 7.open cmd and enter

> jmeter -g D:\Report\TC001_Result.csv -o  C:Report\ReportD

- 8. Go to `C:Report\ReportD` and open `index.html` and you can check your test result

**Note:Should not create any folder with name `ReportD` on same as Jmeter will create and save you report**

Comment: if you define your custom properties, then to the command add `-p youpropertiesfile`, in my experience even after I edited `user.properties` located in same `bin` as jmeter, it did not take them (though maybe partly due to me using alias to jmeter.sh).

Answer (score 31):

JMeter dashboard is only available since JMeter 3.0.

To generate it, see this [tutorial](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M92oYbiVhFw) by one of JMeter developers.

And reference documentation :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

As of JMeter 3.1, It's as easy as calling:

> jmeter -n -t <path_to.jmx> -l <log.jtl> -e -o <dashboard_folder>

If you're looking to learn jmeter correctly, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.

Comment: This doc does not seem clear to me. Can you provide some step-by-step guide for generating simple Report Dashboard? And is it possible to do in GUI mode?

Comment: There is really nothing to do, download JMeter 3.1, run in NON GUI mode as specified in this documentation and you'll get the report. It's not possible in GUI mode which as per best practices is not made for load testing

Comment: Thanks, it is really easy, I just needed this call  `jmeter -n -t <path_to.jmx> -l <log.jtl> -e -o <dashboard_folder>`

Comment: I am getting error Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Results file:/Users/<myusername>/Documents/jmeter/jmeter.log is not empty

Comment: it’s a warning to avoid deleting your files. I youwant them to be deleted add -f option, otherwise change output folder and output file

Answer (score 11):

Report Dashboard module is available in Apache Jmeter3.0 version.Please follow below steps to Generate report dashboard.

1. Open Jmeter from bin folder.
2. In JMeter bin folder you will find `reportgenerator` and `user` properties files.
3. Simply copy all data of Report generator to `user.properties` file.
4. Save the file.
5. Now enter Save.saveservice properties in User.properties file and save it.
6. Now restart JMeter from bin folder.
7. Prepare your test plan.
8. Run your script.
9. Generate your test results in CSV file format.

I have learned in details report generation from here,you can also follow same steps to generate HTML report dashboard.

[Report Dashboard Generation](http://learn-jmeter.blogspot.in/2016/10/how-to-generate-jmeter-report-dashboard.html)

Answer (score 4):

Just give the path in any listener as shown in image, execute the results and check the file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of the apache jmeter [mine is 5.4.3] it seems effortless to generate visual representation out of generated result.
For that,  `Add > Listener > Simple Data Writer`  and in the filename, give the path with  `filename.jtl` and run the tests. Now filename.jtl has been saved to the location with file being created if you didn't have already.
[image]

Now go to that directory and write the following command, it will generate the html file in the given folder in the command and you should be able to see the result with visualization as needed.
`jmeter -g simple-data-writer.jtl -o report`
Note that report is the name of the folder that you want to name. If you go to that report folder, you will see `index.html` there which you can open on the browser.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to generate HTML and CSV report

```
./jmeter.sh -n -t “JPetStore.jmx” -l “JPetStoreLog.csv” -e -o “/home/JPetStoreProject/JPetStoreResult”
```