# jmeter(5.0) load testing and reports generation

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have done load testing with jmeter and my jmeter version is 5.0.

Can you please help me how to generate the reports of the results.

Comment: a similar issue appears here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263768/how-do-i-generate-a-dashboard-report-in-jmeter

Answer (score 2):

Given you [executed JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx -l /path/to/result.csv
```

You can now [generate the HTML Reporting Dashboard from the `result.csv` file as follows](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only):

```
jmeter -g /path/to/result.csv -o /path/to/dashboard/folder
```

The folder where you will be generating the report to must be empty.

Comment: I have done testing in GUI mode

Comment: There is no way you can generate the dashboard out of the GUI run (unless you configure a [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) to store results into a CSV file). Be aware that JMeter GUI is for tests development and debugging only, you should be running load tests in non-GUI mode with all listeners disabled. See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for some JMeter Best Practices

Answer (score 0):

See this new blog (16th january 2019) which explains the while process:

- [Reporting feature in JMeter](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/reporting-feature-in-jmeter/)

Besides, refer to the reference documentation :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html