# Apache JMeter report generation error in MacOs (Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5)

Tags: java, macos, api, testing, jmeter

Getting the below error, when trying the cmd as :
`jmeter -g /path/result/testo1.csv -o /path/result/report`

`An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Consumer failed with message :Begin size 0 is not equal to fixed size 5`

I have already ran the cmd to run the test and generate the csv file properly

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40632832/5291321), but it doesn't worked.

Using Jmeter 5.4.3, installed via brew

java -v :

```
openjdk version "15" 2020-09-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15+36, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug [65838](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65838), the options are in:

1. Downgrade your Java version to [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)
2. Try out the [nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html), there is a chance that the issue is fixed there. However I doubt you will be able to install it using homebrew, you will have to go through the [manual JMeter installation process](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans) (not very complex though)

Comment: tried this also, but still the same error , java version is already 8

Comment: if you do something like `/full/path/to/your/java/8/bin/java -jar /full/path/to/ApacheJMeter.jar -g /full/path/to .jtl file -o /full/path/to/dashboard` it will be successful

Comment: Neither of these solutions worked for me; how can we be sure jmeter is using the correct version of java?